# Detecting Simulator Environment in SPM

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am currently working on a requirement that requires detection of being built for a simulator or device, and upon that, I set binaryTargets to be added or not to a certain target.

Below is a small code that I have written but unfortunately it doesn't work when I change the built environment.

```
var targetSimulator = false
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
targetSimulator = true
#endif
```

The above code sits on Package.swift, but unfortunately such doesn't work. I am curious if there are certain SDKs that compile only for the device, how do we go about to built using SPM?